# Repeating elements in string

Tags: python, string, repeat

Input is the number `25104`, output is supposed to be `225555514444`, therefore each number's count is the same as its value.

I've only found how to repeat the whole string but not elements within a string.

I don't even know where to start so can't include code.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and a [comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions):

```
>>> string = '25104'
>>> ''.join(s*int(s) for s in string)
225555514444
```

This will fail if if there is not an integer in the string because `int` will throw an error if unable to convert.